# HTML CSS Formatting a menu block/hover background

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, block

I would like to know what is the 'correct' way to change my current menu, that looks like this: [image]
to this:
[image]

The problem I have is making the buttons into these blocks that would change background on hover, and the vertical alignment, do I use padding? blocks? table? Help :S

(The color doesn't matter)

CSS:

```
.menu{
        clear: both;
        background-image:url(meniuBG.jpg);
        height:55px;
        line-height: 10px;
      }

.menu a{

        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-style:italic;
        color:rgb(193,193,193);
        margin-right: 25px;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
```

HTML (for no apparent reason):

```
<div class="meniu">

        <a href="#">NAUJIENOS</a>
        <a href="#">KREPSINIO VADOVAS</a>
        <a href="#">TRENIRUOTES</a>
        <a href="#">IDOMYBES</a>
        <a href="#">GALERIJA</a>
        <a href="#">APIE MUS</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't have the background pictures, I don't know if it's of any use then: http://jsfiddle.net/gUhCp/

Comment: Actually here: http://jsfiddle.net/gUhCp/1/ I added black/red boxes instead of the background seen in the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.menu {
        ...
        height:55px;
        /* line-height: 10px;  delete this  */
}

.menu a { 
        ...
        line-height: 55px; /* add this */
}
```

Because you want to center vertically your `<a>` , there is many way to do this you can search on google there's many tuto.

the solution i give you is to make  `line-height` equal to the `heigh` (`55px`). this solution work when your text is just on one line.

and for the hover just make `<a>` `display: inline-block;` and replace `margin` with `padding`

```
.menu a{

text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-style: italic;
color: rgb(193,193,193);
/* margin-right: 25px; */
/* margin-left: 25px; */
padding: 0 25px;
line-height: 55px;
display: inline-block;

}
```

here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DnBR2/2/)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to align it, but what about the hover? it only highlights the text now: http://jsfiddle.net/DnBR2/1/ if I make the 'a' inline-block it highlights it all vertically, but the sides are not highlighted.

Comment: I used display:inline-block and padding-left and right 10px and it seems to be working like in the example now, Thanks though! :)

Comment: good for you i update also my answer if you wanna take a look [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DnBR2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try to add this

```
.menu a{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style:italic;
    color:rgb(193,193,193);
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    line-height:55px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu a:hover{
    background-color: #E7550C;
}
```